# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays

I got 30 double arrays with different values and I want a single loop to initialize all of them. My double arrays looks like this,

```
double[] VALUES0 = new double[] { 27, 62, 125 };
double[] VALUES1 = new double[] { 33, 75, 150 };
double[] VALUES3 = new double[] { 44, 100, 200 };
double[] VALUES4 = new double[] { 50, 112, 225 };
double[] VALUES5 = new double[] { 55, 125, 250 };
```

I made a loop for initialize all of them from VALUES0 to VALUES30 but its showing an exception.

```
double[] VALUES[] = {};

        int x = 27, y = 62, z = 125;

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {

            VALUES[i] = new double[] { x, y, z };

            x += 6;
            y += 13;
            z += 25;
    }
```

Comment: Arrays in java are fixed size and `VALUES` is of size **zero**.

Comment: VALUES[] is empty.then how you access VALUES[i]?

Comment: @dcharms It already is. Java supports this syntax for double arrays as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays in java are fixed size and `VALUES` is of size **zero** because you created it statically (ignoring the bad syntax) with:

```
double[] VALUES[] = {};
```

On top of that, it appears you want to create a two dimensional array.

Arrays in java are objects, and multidimensional arrays in Java are arrays of array *references*. You need to declare and instantiate an array that holds references to double arrays, and create it with the size you need (which is apparently 30). The syntax for that is:

```
double[][] VALUES = new double[30][];
```

Keep in mind that `VALUES` now contains 30 elements set to `null`. Each element can hold a reference to a double array. You have to instantiate and assign each element via `VALUES[i] = new double[someSize];` or with a static initialization as in your example.

Comment: +1 for "array of references". It's quite an important moment of how double-arrays are implemented in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        double[] VALUES[] = new double[30][];

        int x = 27, y = 62, z = 125;

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {

            VALUES[i] = new double[] { x, y, z };

            x += 6;
            y += 13;
            z += 25;
        }
     }
}
```

**Explanation:** *VALUES* is a double-array which is array of arrays in Java. So, before using it you should create it - array of double arrays of size 30.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
    double[] VALUES[] = new double[30][];

    int x = 27, y = 62, z = 125;

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {

        VALUES[i] = new double[]{x, y, z};

        x += 6;
        y += 13;
        z += 25;
    }
```

Comment: How does this differ from the earlier answer?

Comment: Denis Kulagin has the same answer. I didn't noticed it when i post this(few mins different in time)

Answer (score 0):

double[][] VALUES = new double[30][3];

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {

        VALUES[i] = new double[] { x, y, z };

        x += 6;
        y += 13;
        z += 25;
}
```